# Is there Aloha editor plugin with which I can apply custom predefined classes?

Tags: aloha-editor

I would like to apply class to block element with Aloha editor. Core Aloha editor can apply block elements like p, h1, h2, h3. Is there plugin that could add predefined custom classes to those block elements, like p.smaller or h2.crazy, so that result HTML is something like `<h2 class="crazy">Loko headline here<h2>`?